# How to expect an exception and still pass the test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-2.0, nmock

I have this:

```
  Expect.Once.On( someObj ).Method( "SomeMethod" )
    .With(1) // correct value is 2, I want this to fail
    .Will( Throw.Exception( new Exception() ) );
```

An exception is thrown by nmock when it detects that I put 1 instead of 2.  However, the test is failing (red) instead of passing.  How to make this test pass, even though I'm expecting an exception?

Comment: What unit test framework are you using?

Comment: MSTest.  However, it's nmock that I care about here, not how other testing frameworks do this.

Comment: @O.O - NMock is a mocking framework, not a unit testing framework. You will still need to assert the exception thrown from the mock is expected in your tests.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using NUnit then you can do:

```
Assert.Throws<Exception>(() => { someObj.SomeMethod(1); });
```

You can also decorate the test with an `ExpectedException` attribute, although that will cause the test to pass if any `Exception` is thrown, rather than just the statement you want to test.

EDIT: If you're using MSTest, as far as I know, you can only use attributes to expect exceptions i.e.

```
[ExpectedException(typeof(Exception)]
public void TestMethod() { ... }
```

You should consider throwing a more specific exception type from your mock and expecting that type instead of a plain `Exception`.

You could also define your own method to replicate the NUnit functionality:

```
public static class ExceptionAssert
{
    public static void Throws<T>(Action act) where T : Exception
    {
        try
        {
            act();
        }
        catch (T ex)
        {
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Assert.Fail(string.Format("Unexpected exception of type {0} thrown", ex.GetType().Name));
        }

        Assert.Fail(string.Format("Expected exception of type {0}", typeof(T).Name));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[ExpectedException (typeof(Exception))]
```

Edit: thanks, don't have the studio right now and was not 100% sure about the syntax.

Comment: I think this has been deprecated. The recommended version is what @Lee suggested.

Comment: Is that builtin for mstest or we'll need some custom extension method for something like that.

Comment: Sorry thought he was using NUnit.